# MapKit did crash iPad application on modalPresentation

Tags: ios, ipad, mapkit

I try to load a map with `MapKit` inside `UIViewController` with `modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet`

This work, but if I dismiss my controller before the map is totally loaded, the application crash. So, I need to stop the loading map before to dismiss my controller.

After some search, I didn't found solution to stop the loading. Do you have idea to fix this bug ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting your MapView to nil in the `viewDidUnload:` method of your controller ?

```
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    self.mapView = nil;
}
```

This is what Apple recommends and does in the example code, for example [WorldCities](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/WorldCities/Listings/Classes_MapViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009466-Classes_MapViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_6)